# Android Studio Intent.putExtra Error

Tags: android, android-intent

[image] [Intent.putExtra Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FdRm.png)

I have no idea whats happening in my program.
I've tried parcelable, serializable, CharSequence & String.valueOf to avoid the error but it crash when I debuging run this line every time.

I check out most tutorial using same method but no error founded, What is the problem and how can I fix this.

Thank you.

Comment: post your code and error log along with query.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7827593/4146722

Comment: Hover your mouse to the redlines and it will show the specific issue.

Comment: is Player class implements `parcelable` OR  `serializable` interface.

Answer (score 0):

object can't be put in extras directly it have to serialize then pass to intend
you can use this
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/